# Database error: SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

include_once __DIR__ . '/../includes/DatabaseConnection.php';
include_once __DIR__ . '/../includes/totalJokes.php';

function query($pdo,$sql,$parameters=[]){
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    foreach($parameters as $name=>$value){
        $query->bindValue($name,$value);
    }
    $query->execute();
    return $query;
}
function getJoke($pdo,$id){

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `joke` WHERE `id`= :id';
    $parameters = [':id'=>$id];
    $row = query($pdo,$query,$parameters);
    return $row->fetch();
}

function insertJoke($pdo,$joketext,$authorid){
    $parameters = [':joketext'=>$joketext,'authorid:'=>$authorid];
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `joke` SET `joketext`= :joketext,
    `jokedate` = CURDATE(), `authorid`= :authorid';
    query($pdo,$query,$parameters);
}
function updateJoke($pdo,$id,$joketext,$authorid){
    $parameters = [':authorid'=>$authorid, ':joketext'=> $joketext, ':id'=>$id];
    $query = 'UPDATE `joke` SET `authorid`= :authorid,`joketext`= :joketext WHERE `id`= :id';
    query($pdo,$query,$parameters);

}
?>
```

I get the following error when function insertJoke() is called.

> Database error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter
>   was not defined in:
>   /home/vagrant/Code/Project/includes/DatabaseFunctions.php11

Comment: you have typo in the first line of `insertJoke` : `authorid:` should be `:authorid`

Comment: Error describes the `insertJoke()` function parameter does not match.

Comment: how are you calling `insertJoke()` ?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['joketext'])){
    try{
        include __DIR__ . '/../includes/DatabaseFunctions.php';
        insertJoke($pdo,$_POST['joketext'],1)    }

Comment: Thanks for help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an invalid parameter.

`authorid:` does not exist. The `:` should be before not after

`$parameters = [':joketext'=>$joketext,':authorid'=>$authorid];`

Comment: Thank you i overlooked it. Its sloved